# Intellij IDEA 12 - Unable to set condition to breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe

I'm trying to debug haxe. in this [link](http://www.screenr.com/9oN8) it's shown how to do it. A condition property should be set to breakpoint to enable debugging. But I cannot do this in Intellij 12. I can't write anything to "Condition" area.  [image] Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the breakpoints in your class? That should open the condition dialog. And what's your target (Flash, JS,...)? And finally, have you try it with IntelliJ 13? It works perfectly for me